# "public://" is not resolved correctly to the full path

Tags: files

In my script, `public://` resolves to http://./sites/default/files/test.txt

This is the code I used to get the actual value for `public://`:

```
$path = file_create_url('public://test.txt');
```

`$GLOBALS['base_url']` is also resolving to http://.

Any idea why the domain is missing from the `public://`?

Thanks

Comment: What's the context? Are you executing the script in Drush?

Comment: This is a script I'm running from the command line. It's in the root and Drupal bootstrap has loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason there's no `$base_url` is because the script you're running isn't in a HTTP context; when Drupal bootstraps, unless you've specified a `$base_url` in **settings.php**, it [retrieves this value](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_settings_initialize/7) from `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` which doesn't exist in the command line context.

To remedy this, you can set the `$base_url` in your **settings.php** or, if you're running Drush, use the `--uri` argument.

```
drush scr --uri="http://www.example.com" my_script.php
```